# ionic android back button navigation to previous page not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework, back

I am trying to add back button navigation in ionic1 app, I have registered the 
back button in `.run(function($ionicPlatform)` by adding code

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Back button will DO NOTHING.
      //alert("Going back!!!");
    }, 100);
```

and it prevents android back button to close the app but I am unable to go to previous page. SO far I have tried

```
$ionicHistory.goBack();
```

and

```
$state.go('menu.home');
```

but they dont work. How can I call previous page everytime back button is pressed ?

Here are some of the states from routes.js:

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider


      .state('menu.home', {
    url: '/page1',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('menu', {
    url: '/side-menu21',
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'menuCtrl'
  })

  .state('menu.policySummaries', {
    url: '/page4',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/policySummaries.html',
        controller: 'policySummariesCtrl'
      }
    }
  }) 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/side-menu21/page1')


});
```

Comment: have you tried `window.history.back();`

Comment: @Edison wow u are genius its working in android emulator.
How can I make sure that it closes the app when back button is pressed in home page. The state of my home page is:
`.state('menu.home', {
    url: '/page1',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })`

Answer (score 0):

This works just make sure to inject $state and $ionicPopup in .run function:

```
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
      if ($state.current.name == "menu.hPCompliance") {
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
          title: 'Exit',
          template: 'Are you sure you want to close the app?',
          okText: "Yes",
          okType: "button-positive",
          cancelText: "No",
          cancelType: "button-assertive"
        });
        confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
          if (res) {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
          } else {
            console.log('Cancel');
          }
        });
      }
      else {
        window.history.back();
      }
```